# Create type {...} from type Array<{...}>

Tags: typescript, types

I created a type in TypeScript:

```
type SomeType = Array<{...}>;
```

It defines an array of objects with many different properties in place of the `...`.

I'd like to create another type that should have the exact same structure as `SomeType`, just without the array ..so basically I need only that object definition from it like:

```
type SomeOtherType = {...};
```

Is there some way to create `SomeOtherType` based on `SomeType` so I don't have to list all properties of that object again creating redundancy in the code?

I don't want to use interfaces this time, I'd like to know how this would be possible with types.

I read [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) but couldn't figure it out based on the docs. Maybe mapped types is what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
type SomeType = Array<{...}>;
```

you can get the type `{...}` by looking at the first position using *lookup types*:

```
type SomeOtherType = SomeType[0];
```